# Is there a formula to calculate the length of line segment $x$ where $x$ branches off from an angle of a triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

It's best shown by an image:
[(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6Yxf.png)

where the angle $A$, $B$, and $C$ can be any known angle and the lengths of the line segments that make up the triangle can be any known length and line $x$ would be the only unknown. Line $x$ would also be exactly twice the length from where angle $B$ would intersect line segment $AC$.

I know there is a formula for when it is a right triangle, but I'm wondering if there is one for a non-right triangle, or if there needs to be extra information.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what are the known quantities, and which ones are the unknown

Comment: The only unknown would be the value of line x.

Comment: What defines the endpoint of this line segment $x$? Based on your picture it seems I could make it any length I want. You may be interested in the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) which generalizes the Pythagorean theorem to non-right triangles.

Comment: It would be exactly twice the length from the angle $B$ to the line segment $AC$

Comment: @NotSp33dy, it is important to include this information in the body of your question.

Comment: What defines the direction of that segment? Is that a parameter?

Comment: It would be helpful to see formula for the right triangle